# How to change the opacity of a WPF control from 0 to 100% only when a certain key combination is pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an `Button` on a View whose `Opacity` is set to 0.

I am looking for a way to make the `Button` appear (by making its Opacity=100%) ONLY when a certain key combination is pressed so that it becomes clickable. Let's assume the key combination is `LeftShift` and `LeftCtrl`.

But, as soon as the keys being pressed change by either:

1. pressing another key in addition to the chosen 'combination'
2. releasing all keys
3. releasing some of the keys that form the 'combination'

I would like the Opacity to return to 0.

I can get it to sort of work by handling the Views `Preview..._KeyDown` event like:

```
   private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        {
            btn.Opacity = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            btn.Opacity = 0;
        }

    }
```

The issue with this is that I have to press another key in order to reset the Opacity to 0;

Here is the simple XAML for completeness:

```
<Window x:Class="TestOpacityKeyCombination.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestOpacityKeyCombination"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
<Grid>
    <Button Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100"  x:Name="btn" Opacity="0"/> 
</Grid>
</Window>
```

How might I get this to work the way I want?

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you work with Opacity instead of Visibility?

Comment: @RandRandom I'm going with Opacity so I can eventually fade it in gradually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PreviewKeyUp` event.

Here is your XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestOpacityKeyCombination.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestOpacityKeyCombination"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="Window_PreviewKeyUp">
<Grid>
    <Button Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100"  x:Name="btn" Opacity="0"/> 
</Grid>
```

and c# code

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        {
            Menu.Opacity = 1;
            if (IsAnyKeyDown())
            {
                Menu.Opacity = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Menu.Opacity = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //set opacity back to 1 if PressedUp key is not LeftCtrl and LeftShift
        if(!Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.LeftCtrl) && !Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.LeftShift))
        {
            Menu.Opacity = 1;
            return;
        }
        Menu.Opacity = 0;
    }

    public static bool IsAnyKeyDown()
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key));

        foreach (var v in values)
            if (((Key)v) != Key.None && 
                ((Key)v) != Key.LeftCtrl && 
                ((Key)v) != Key.LeftShift && 
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown((Key)v))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sadly this fails my point (1). That is, pressing more keys in addition to the SHIFT and CTRL fail to hide the Button.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the problem properly. I updated the code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `PreviewKeyUp` event to check if the released key is a key of a valid combination:

```
List<Key> validKeys { get; } = new List<Key> {Key.LeftCtrl, Key.LeftShift};

private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  btn.Opacity = 0;

  List<Key> invalidKeys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key))
    .Cast<Key>()
    .Except(this.ValidKeys)
    .ToList();
  invalidKeys.Remove(Key.None);

  var keyboardDevice = e.Device as KeyboardDevice;

  // Check if combination is active
  if (this.ValidKeys.All(keyboardDevice.IsKeyDown))
  {
    // Check if additional keys are pressed
    if (invalidKeys.Any(keyboardDevice.IsKeyDown))
    {
      return;
    }

    btn.Opacity = 1;
  }
}

private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Check if the combination is invalid
  if (this.ValidKeys.Contains(e.Key))
  {
    btn.Opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sadly this fails my point (1). That is, pressing more keys in addition to the SHIFT and CTRL fail to hide the Button.